# Mongoose collection that keeps only X items

Tags: mongodb, collections, mongoose

Is there a simple way to create a MongoDB collection that keeps only X records?

I mean, if X is 10 at 11th record inserted it should delete the last one to keep always at max 10 records.

Comment: I see several approach, for example `find().sort().limit(10)` and clean periodically or delete before/after each insert.